# Google Sheets Timestamp on New Row creation

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to add a timestamp on a new row that is created in Google Sheets.

So whenever a new row is created, one of the cells in that row will have a timestamp reflecting when the row was created.

Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this function:

```
function addTimeStamp(e) {
  var typeOfChange = e.changeType;

  //Logger.log('typeOfChange: ' + typeOfChange);

  //Logger.log('typeof typeOfChange: ' + typeof typeOfChange);

  if (typeOfChange === "INSERT_ROW") {
    var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    var activeRangeIs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
    //Logger.log(activeRangeIs);

    var whatRow = activeRangeIs.getRow();

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(whatRow, 3).setValue(timeStamp);
  };

};
```

Then use an *installable trigger*.  Resources menu, Current Project Triggers.